# folder path in sublime text build system

Tags: sublimetext2

My sublime project looks like this:

```
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "folder_exclude_patterns":
            [
                ".bzr",
                "build",
                "webapps",
                "work",
                ".settings"
            ],
            "path": "/home/charles/project/Editor/trunk"
        }
    ],
    "settings":
    {
        "build_on_save": true,
        "filename_filter": "\\.(java)$",
        "tab_size": 4,
        "translate_tabs_to_spaces": false
    },
    "build_systems":
    [
        {
            "name": "compile",
            "cmd": ["ant", "-f", "dev.xml", "compile"]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I save a file the console says:

```
Buildfile: dev.xml does not exist!
Build failed
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

I know that I need to put something before dev.xml but I don't know what.

I found some possibilities here: http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html#variables

But What I need is the folder path "/home/charles/project/Editor/trunk" in my case...

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried to replace "dev.xml" by "/path/to/dev.xml"?

Comment: Yes it work but I want to use the command for many folders.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing "working_dir" in your "build_systems" setup. The example below will use the directory that holds the sublime project file as the build starting directory.

```
"build_systems":
[
    {
        "name": "compile",
        "working_dir": "${project_path}",
        "cmd": ["ant", "-f", "dev.xml", "compile"]
    }
]
```

More information can be found at: http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/projects.html